# Computing the exponential generating function of the Bell numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to compute the exponential generating function of the Bell numbers $B_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nkB_k, B_1=1$. So far I have
\begin{align}
B(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk B_k \frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk \frac{x^n}{n!},
\end{align}
where we can interchange the order of summation by monotone convergence or Tonelli's theorem. But I have no idea how to compute $\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{x^n}{k!(n-k)!}$. According to Mathematica,
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{x^n}{k!(n-k)!}  = \frac{e^x x^k}{k!}.
$$
As shown in the answer,
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{x^n}{k!(n-k)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+k}}{k!n!} = x^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{x^ke^x}{k!}.$$

Hence
$$
B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k \frac{e^xx^k}{k!} = e^x \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x B(x).
$$
But this does not make sense, as $B(x) = e^xB(x)$ implies that $B(x)=0$. What error have I made?

Edit: It turns out that $$B(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom nk B_k\frac{x^n}{n!},$$ so what I computed above was actually $B'(x)$. This yields the differential equation $B'(x) = e^x B(x)$, from which $B(x) = Ce^{e^x}$. The condition $B(0)=1$ yields $C=\frac1e$, so that $$B(x) = e^{e^x-1}. $$

Comment: Is there a typo in your recurrence relation ? Shouldn't the Bell numbers be sums of Stirling numbers of the second kind ?

Comment: @Simon Yes, there was a typo. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an error in your second line. Using $B_0=1$, you should get
$$B(x)=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkB_k\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$
I would now differentiate....

Comment: Differentiating yields
$$
B'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom nk B_k \frac{x^n}{n!},
$$
but this is what I had before. So $B'(x) = e^xB(x)$, whence $B(x) = Ce^{-e^{-x}}$. The result should be $e^{e^x-1}$, so again I have erred...

Comment: @Math1000 I think this time your error is in solving the differential equation.

Comment: Ah, I accidentally solved $B'(x)e^x = B(x)$. So indeed the solution to $B'(x) = e^xB(x)$ is $B(x)=Ce^{e^{x}}$, and from $B(0) = 1$ we have $1 = Ce^{e^0}=Ce$, so that $C=\frac1e$ and hence $$B(x) = \frac1e e^{e^x} =  e^{e^x-1},$$ as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{x^n}{k!(n-k)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+k}}{k!n!} = \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n!} = \frac{x^ke^x}{k!}$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it would be as simple as shifting the index.